# In recycleview onclick item how to change the color of other item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a quiz app. Could not figure out how to change the color of other item when one item in recycleview is clicked.When option 2 is clicked but the correct option is option 1 it should display as given below in picture. Solution please
[image]

Comment: are you using arraylist with model class to infalte the recyclerview???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two drawable files for selected and unselected buttons in your drawable folder.

Create a model class as below:

```
public class ModelDemo
{
   //your declaration

boolean isClicked;

  public void setIsClicked(boolean value) {
            this.value = value ;
        }

public boolean isClicked() {
           return value;
        }
}
```

//Now create an arraylist of type model like `ArrayList<ModelDemo>` , with other values you need to infalte your recyclerview. Set the isClicked to false initially. Inflate your recylerview as follows

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {

          final ModelDemo modelDemo= arrayZipModel.get(position);

      //here write your code to inflate the data for button text




     if (modelDemo.isClicked())
               holder.yourButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.selected));
            else
                  holder.yourButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unselected));




            holder.yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(modelDemo.isClicked())
                      modelDemo.setIsClicked(false)
                  else
                     modelDemo.setIsClicked(true)

                   notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });



        }
```

Comment: You specified clicked in your question,please edit it to make it more specific. By the way,you can treat it in any way you can...the main purpose is to change the view and notify the adapter, so that changes persist.