# Change recyclerView item background onClick?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would make that when I press a button in my `recyclerView` that will change it background color so it will be visible that is pressed but I'm not very into android so I can't get how to do it.

I've tried some guides found online but most of them didn't worked for me, like in this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798421/in-recycleview-onclick-item-how-to-change-the-color-of-other-item) the buttons were not getting their color and were just white.
I would do somethink like that
[screen of my activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twLnt.png)

Here is my `recyclerView` Adapter code:

```
public class RecyclerViewMenu extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewMenu.MenuViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<MenuConstructor> menuConstructors;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public interface  OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    onItemClickListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menucard,parent,false);
    return new MenuViewHolder(v, onItemClickListener);

}


RecyclerViewMenu(ArrayList<MenuConstructor> menuList){
    menuConstructors = menuList;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MenuViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    MenuConstructor currentItem = menuConstructors.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(currentItem.getDesk());
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(currentItem.getSfondoColor()));
    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(currentItem.getFontColor()));



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return menuConstructors.size();
}

public static class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textView;

    MenuViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonName);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }


            }
        });



    }
}
```

}

Actually if I press on of the button's it's load on the upped `RecyclerView` different items like if "CICCIO" is pressed upper it will load some stuff if another button is pressed it will load other items and if I use quick learner answer that's what happens

[Gif of activity that change items by pressing buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEN3Q.gif)

[Here after using quick learner solution it's change color but not anymore the items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae5JE.gif)

Comment: What do you want ? the background stay in the next color ? like a selector? or just for the press state?

Comment: @JCDecary if i press it i would that it remain on it color until i press another button

Comment: Do you toggle between two color ? or more ?

Comment: Actually when the button is selected will be always green but the other colors can be different like one button blue one red etc.

Comment: I don't know what you're model look like. But you will need to add a logic to know what color to show. And change the variable of you object press than refresh view with notifiyDataSetChanged... or notifyItemChanged(position);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this  if you want to change the color of selected item in recycler view

```
 public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.ViewHolder> {
            private int selected_position = -1;

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(PlacesLocationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                if (selected_position == position) {
                    // do your stuff here like
                    //Change selected item background color 

                } else {
                      // do your stuff here like
                      //Change  unselected item background color 
                }
              // rest of the code here

       }


    }
```

and this `MenuViewHolder` class should be like this

```
public static class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textView;

    MenuViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonName);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                         selected_position = position;
                         notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }


            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: The code works but i have some issues with it like i had using other guides, if i use onBindView the setOnClickListener that make that i can't change between the recyclerViews i will post now 2 gifs for explain it better

Comment: added the 2 GIF'S on my question

Comment: i can't use notifyDataSetChanged on MenuViewHolder cus it's not static method and even selected_position

Comment: Great solved by making MenuViewHolder not static, thank you so much

Comment: did it finally help you dear?

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` will refresh the whole list which in most cases wouldn't be very desirable. Instead you can keep a reference to the previously selected item and call `notifyItemChanged(previousItem)` if the index isn't `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` followed by `notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)`

Comment: @Quicklearner thank you so much . you saved my day :D

Comment: I am glad it worked for you :D @Liya

Answer (score 3):

To change the background of a clicked item in the RecyclerView you need to catch the click in the adapter using an iterface:

```
interface ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClickListener(item: Item, position: Int)
}
```

When we click we will get the item and the items position. In our bind function in the adapter we will set the on click listener on your button:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener {
    onClickListener.onItemClickListener(item, position)
}
```

In your activity you will then implement this interface:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ItemAdapter.ItemClickListener {
```

Next we need to implement the background changing logic on item click. The logic is this: when the user clicks on an item, we check if the background on the clicked item is white (the item is not previously clicked) and if this condition is true, we change the background on all of the items in the RecyclerView to white (to invalidate previously clicked and marked items if there are any) and then change the background color of the clicked item to teal to mark it. And if the background of the clicked item is teal (which means the user clicks again on the same previously marked item), we change the background color on all of the items to white. First we will need to get our item background color as a ColorDrawable. We will use an iterator function to go through all of the items (children) of the RecyclerView and forEach() function to change the background on everyone of them. This method will look like this:

```
 override fun onItemClickListener(item: Item, position: Int) {
        val itemBackground: ColorDrawable =
            binding.recycler[position].background as ColorDrawable
        if (itemBackground.color == ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)) {
            binding.recycler.children.iterator().forEach { item ->
                item.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.white
                    )
                )
            }
            binding.recycler[position].setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.teal_200)
            )
        } else {
            binding.recycler.children.iterator().forEach { item ->
                item.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.white
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

So now you change the background on item click, if you click the same item, you will change the background back to what it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Put color resource id in MenuConstructor this class. And set color from this class to itemView in onBind. And whenever you click button so change color in MenuConstructor this class on perticular position.

After Changing the color in MenuConstructor this class, Just notifyDataSetChanged() call this method.

In onBind,

```
holder.textView.setTag(position);
holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
//change color in this
notifiDataSetChanged();
}
        });
```

Comment: i have yet the resource id for the color in the Constructor with get and set method but i can't get how to set that onClick it will become green and when i press another button it will return back to old color