# How to change background color of more than one recyclerView item using one button?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a button. when I click that button my app should look like 2nd one.
**before clicking button:**
[image]

**after clicking button background color of some item will be changed. like this:**
[image]

Comment: for this you have to set flag in its data array isSelected = false, when you select an item set this boolean to true, and in bind viewHolder check  is isSelected is true then change color else normal color for unselected

Comment: I have an arrayList called isSelected and I have true value for those which are selected.  But how will I change when button clicked?  Can you give me the code or tell step by step.(I am a beginner). <br> extra: I can select one and dis select it by clicking on it. But I how do I change color more than one item using button.

Comment: by using interface set in adapter and use it in respective activity

Comment: can you give me code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194044/how-to-properly-highlight-selected-item-on-recyclerview

Comment: Go through with this stack once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875775/change-recyclerview-item-background-onclick

Comment: already solved, forgot  to comment